# Stop a javascript timer and animation and resume them

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I have to stop a timer and an animation of a bar which width is decreasing dependently on a *time* variable and then resume both if pressed a button, so that the bar animation will continue from where it stopped and the same for the timer. How can I do that?

I can execute a function on button press, it's just the stopping and resuming functions that I don't know.

`$("#timebar")` is the animated bar.

```
function startTimer() {
    timer = setTimeout(function(){ 
        barAnimation();
    }, time);
}

function stopTimer() {
    $('#timebar').stop();
    $('#timebar').css("width","100%");
    clearTimeout(timer);
}

function barAnimation() {
    $("#timebar").animate({ width: "0%" }, time, "linear");
}
```

Comment: Any specific reason you need a timer?

Comment: It's a game, you lose a life if the time is up. If you make the correct choice the timer and animation will reset.

Comment: @Shikkediel you shouldn't have deleted your answer because I found your solution the best and just when I was about to select your reply as sollution you deleted it. I'm sorry for the time you've waited but I couldn't look at the answers before.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have the animation, but it does offer a start/stop and progress indicator.

```js
var time = 0;
var timer = 0;
var running = false;

function startTimer() {
  running = true;
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    barAnimation();
  }, 1000);
}

function stopTimer() {
  running = false;
  clearInterval(timer);
}

function barAnimation() {
  time++;
  $("#count").text(time);
  $("#timebar").prop("value", time);
}

$("#go").on("click", function(evt) {
  if (running) {
    stopTimer();
  } else {
    startTimer();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="go">Go</button>

<progress id="timebar" value="0" max="100"></progress>

<div id="count"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this is what you're looking for:

```js
var time = 0;
var remaining = 15000;
var interval;

$('#start').click(startTimer);
$('#stop').click(stopTimer);

function startTimer() {
    if (!interval) {
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            if (remaining % 1000 === 0)
                $('#time').html(time++);
            remaining -= 100;
          }, 100); // 100 w/ modulo instead of 1000 for better precision
        barAnimation();
    }
}

function stopTimer() {
    $('#timebar').stop();
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = false;
}

function barAnimation() {
    $("#timebar").animate({ width: "0%" }, remaining, "linear");
}
```

```css
#timebar {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<div id="time">0</div>
<div id="timebar"></div>
```